# PyCall not working with a specific module

Tags: julia

I have been trying to call a specific python module ( https://github.com/wmayner/pyemd ) but I keep getting the followin error message:

> ERROR: PyError (:PyImport_ImportModule) 
>       ImportError('No module named emd',)
>         File "/home/humberto/.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/lib/python2.7/pyemd/**init**.py", line 63, in 
>           from .emd import emd
>        in pyerr_check at /home/humberto/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:56 [inlined]
>        in pyerr_check at /home/humberto/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:61 [inlined]
>        in macro expansion at /home/humberto/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/exception.jl:81 [inlined]
>        in pyimport(::String) at /home/humberto/.julia/v0.5/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:387

However, I am able to call python functions such as *"Hello world"* and I can use the module in a python environment. Do anyone knows a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have not installed `pyemd`. Be careful, even if you installed `pyemd` through system's `python`, in your installation, `PyCall` uses local install of `python` by `Conda` package. Look at `pyimport_conda` function, it installs the package if not already installed and imports it.